# Uniform approximation of a continuous function on $[0,1]$ by polynomials with a control on the uniform norm of the polynomials

Tags: approximation-theory, weierstrass-approximation

Let $f \in C([0,1])$. By the Weierstrass approximation theorem, it is possible to uniformly approximate $f$ on $[0,1]$ by a sequence of polynomials $P_i$.

(i) Can we also require that $\|P_i\|_\infty \leq \|f\|_\infty$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$?

(ii) Can we also require $|P_i(x)| \leq |f(x)|$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in [0,1]$?

Note: this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846337/approximating-continuous-function-on-0-1-by-monotone-increasing-polynomials) is related but not quite the same.

Comment: Define $ \lambda_n f(x)$ an auxiliary sequence of functions, such that $\lambda_n $ increases to $1$.  For each $n$ consider the sequence $\lbrace P_i^n \rbrace$ defined by the Weierstrass aproximation and use a diagonal argument. This works if $f$ does not reaches zero. Otherwise if $f$ is zero in an interval and is not the null function then $ii)$ is impossible.

Comment: (ii) cannot be required. Consider $f(x)= 0$ for $0\le x\le 1/2,$ and $f(x)=x-1/2$ for $x>1/2.$ Then (ii) cannot be  satisfied on $0\le x\le 1/2,$ Part (i) holds. It is a general fact concerning normed spaces.